# Rest Assured and selenium integration

Tags: selenium, rest-assured

I have a rest assured automation framework written and it is working well as of now. Now We have a to integrate api and UI testing.

Steps would be:

1. Using Rest assured hit a Login API and get all required tokens
2. Using Selenium - launch browser and hit the URL- SOMEHOW (???) pass the tokens generated in step 1 to browser (i.e to driver) so that logged in session opens up for that URL-

So basically automation need not login again in step 2 and just use token generated in step 1. driver will directly start actions on logged in page.

Is this even possible? if Yes, it will be great help to know some pointers..

Comment: `Selenium` could be used to just generate those tokens for you.

Comment: In the first place why would need this kind of login as in the real time the end user would login via the login page & you should try doing that via selenium?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe i'm over simplifying this but i believe all you need to do is deserialize your response, grab the tokens and store them as variables. When you turn around and log in with selenium you should be able to pass those into your request as needed (whether that's in the URL or in some field).